# How to combine functions to get several types of information

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3, youtube, youtube-api

I use the Youtube Api to get information about a single video. When I do a request with an url like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status,snippet,contentdetails&id=$videoID&key=$apikey
```

I get all the info which I need. The problem is that I can not find a way to combine the functions that I have to get the information in one go.

What I got so far:

```
function getDescription($videoID){
    $apikey = "<MYKEY>";

    $desc = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$videoID&key=$apikey");
    $description =json_decode($desc, true);
    foreach ($description['items'] as $videodesc)
   {
       $description= $videodesc['snippet']['description'];
   }
   return $description;
}

function getPublishedAt($videoID){
    $apikey = "<MYKEY>";

    $pub = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$videoID&key=$apikey");
    $publish =json_decode($pub, true);
    foreach ($publish['items'] as $published)
   {
       $publish= $published['snippet']['publishedAt'];
   }

   $publish = new DateTime($publish);
   $publish = $publish->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

   return $publish;

}

echo "<br>Description: ";
echo getDescription("<VIDEO-ID>");
echo "<br>PublishedAt: ";
echo getPublishedAt("<VIDEO-ID>");
```

So, this code works, but I like to do ONE request to the api (using multiple parts in the url) and get the information.

Does anyone has a clue how to do this using one function only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself:

```
$videoinfo = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=<video-id>&part=snippet,status,contentDetails,statistics&part=statistics&key=<api-key>");
   $videoinfo =json_decode($videoinfo, true);
   foreach ($videoinfo['items'] as $embed)
   {
       $emb= $embed['status']['embeddable'];
       $license= $embed['status']['license'];
       $duration= $embed['contentDetails']['duration'];
   }
echo $emb;   
echo $license;
echo $duration;
```

It's not a function, but this will do the tric :)